# SSH Host key checking to Drobear - accept a fingerprint for one time

Tags: ssh, dropbear

I installed a remote and headless ubuntu box with full disk encryption and dropbear to unlock it by ssh.

I accepted the "standard" host key in my configuration - but now, on every reboot, I have to edit my known_hosts or add -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' to the ssh command. But this is bad - a mitm to catch my luks passphrase is a realistic attack vector...

Is there an option to add two host keys for one Host or an explicit "-o AcceptHostKey [fingerprint]" option in ssh?

Answer (score 1):

Create a DNS alias for the host.

- hostname -> regular SSH
- hostname-unlock -> unlock SSH